# No exec permissions on programs in /usr/local/bin

Tags: permissions, osx, executable

I have installed the newest Erlang from source. As the final step I have executed

```
 sudo make install
```

Among other things, it placed erl link in /usr/local/bin, but its permissions are insufficient for me to use, other than with sudo

```
 lrwxr-x---  1 root  wheel    21B Apr 19 22:26 erl@
```

/usr/local/bin permissions:

```
 drwxr-xr-x  18 root  wheel   612B Apr 20 21:45 bin/
```

sudo gives enough permissions to execute, but not enough to change the permissions. The question is, how do I change the permissions on these symbolic links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using chmod's `-h` option (from the man page: "-h  If the file is a symbolic link, change the mode of the link itself rather than the file that the link points to")?  I tried it, and it seemed to do the job:

```
sudo chmod -h o+rx erl
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are MacOS root files protected by Apple's **System Integrity Protection**
If path is set properly, it won't require root permissions to execute a symbolic link.
I wouldn't recommend, but you can allow user access by:
 `sudo chown -r $(whoami) /usr/local/bin`
What is your current path? Heres mine for an example:
`echo $PATH`
*/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin*